# Getting substring starting by char

Tags: javascript

I know that js `substring` method accept number parameters but what if I need to get a part of string beginning with `?`. So the method must accept a char value for beginning position. How can I do this?

> http://localhost:8080/new_prog_24/search.action?country=&city=&sex=1&beginage=16&endage=65&children=&confession=0#2

Comment: You can find the position with `indexOf`and after that you can get the string with `substing`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Read the documentation of the methods available on strings at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you the results (unless I am understanding your question incorrectly, apologies if I did):-

```
index = myString.indexOf("?");
var mysubString = "";

if(index == 0) //<--- only for strings that are beginning with a "?"
{
   mysubString = myString.Substring(1, myString.length);
}
```

this should get you a string that starts with a "?" but without displaying the "?" as part of your substring...until the end of the string.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I assumed by JS you meant Javascript

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gmb1garj/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `indexOf` method so that you know where is the `"?"` char.

```
var test = "is this a test? Yes it is!";
var startAt = test.indexOf('?') + 1; // + 1 so that '?' is not returned
test.substring(startAt);
```

Comment: for some reason I get
`Uncaught TypeError: uri.indexOf is not a functionrefreshByHash @ search_pagin_script.js:12x.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5`